# ipojo publisher subscriber event admin handler - not getting output

Tags: java, maven, events, handler, ipojo

So I've spent days on this and it's still not working for me.

I'm posting a simpler example, while trying to follow the tutorial [http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/describing-components/event-admin-handlers.html]

Any help to make it work would be much appreciated. The projects compile and run. But the publisher does not send any data. Infact when I user m_publisher.sendData(data); the outputs to the console from run(), starting() and stopping() stop showing as well.

What am I doing wrong?

MyPubComponent.java

```
    package ipojo.osgi.example.pub;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Invalidate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Validate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.Publishes;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.publisher.Publisher;
    import org.osgi.service.event.Event;

    @Component
    @Instantiate
    public class MyPubComponent implements Runnable{


        @Publishes( // or @Publisher before the 1.7.0
          name="myPublisher",
          topics="mssg",
          dataKey="my.data",
          synchronous=true
          ) 
        private Publisher m_publisher;

        @Validate
        public void starting() {
              Thread thread = new Thread(this);
          thread.start();
          System.out.println("Publisher Started");
          }

        @Invalidate
        public void stopping() {
         // s_logger.info("EventPublihser stoppted");
          System.out.println("Publisher Stopped");

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
          String data = "hello world";
          System.out.println("Sending data...");
          m_publisher.sendData(data);
        }
    }
```

metadata.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ipojo
        xmlns:ev="org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event">
        <component className="ipojo.osgi.example.pub.MyPubComponent">
            <ev:publisher
                name="myPublisher"
                field="m_publisher"
                topics="mssg"
                data-key="my.data"
                synchronous=true />
        </component>
        <instance component="ipojo.osgi.example.pub.MyPubComponent" name="dataPublisher"/>
    </ipojo>
```

pom.xml

```
    <project>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <packaging>bundle</packaging>
      <groupId>ipojo.osgi.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>mypub</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <name>Publisher</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.ipojo.handler.eventadmin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.event</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
             <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
             <version>4.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
             <artifactId>org.apache.felix.ipojo</artifactId>
             <version>1.12.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

      <build>
         <plugins>
         <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.0</version>
         <extensions>true</extensions>
         <configuration>
           <instructions>
             <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
             <Private-Package>ipojo.osgi.example.mypub</Private-Package>
           </instructions>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-ipojo-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.12.1</version>
               <executions>
                 <execution>
                 <goals>
                       <goal>ipojo-bundle</goal>
                </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

MySubComponent.java

```
    package ipojo.osgi.example.sub;

    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Validate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Invalidate;
    import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.Subscriber;

    @Component
    @Instantiate
    public class MySubComponent implements Runnable {

        @Subscriber(
          name="mySubscriber",
          topics="mssg",
          dataKey="my.data",
          dataType="java.lang.String")
          private void handleData(String s) {
            // Event received
            // Do something with the event
            System.out.println("Recieved = "+s);
          }        

        @Validate
        public void start() {
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            System.out.println("Reciever Started");
        }

        @Invalidate
        public void stop() {
            System.out.println("Reciever Stopped");
        }    

        @Override
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("Reciever Running");
        }
    }
```

metadata.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ipojo
        xmlns:ev="org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event">
        <component className="ipojo.osgi.example.sub.MySubComponent">
            <ev:subscriber
                name="mySubscriber"
                callback="handleData"
                topics="mssg"
                data-key="my.data"
                data-type="String"
                synchronours=true />
        </component>
        <instance component="ipojo.osgi.example.sub.MySubComponent" name="DataReciever"/>
    </ipojo>
```

Output:

```
    g! Reciever Started
    Reciever Running
    lb
    START LEVEL 1
       ID|State      |Level|Name
        0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.2.1)
        1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
        2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
        3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
        4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
        5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO (1.12.1)
        6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO Gogo Command (1.12.1)
        7|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO Event Admin Handler (1.8.0)
        8|Active     |    1|org.osgi:org.osgi.service.event (1.3.1.201505202024)
        9|Active     |    1|Subscriber (1.0.0)
       10|Active     |    1|Publisher (1.0.0)
    g
```

Comment: I don't know the felix maven plugin: unless it picks up the ipojo dependency automatically I'd expect you'd have to include ipojo as an explicit dependency in the pom.xml yourself.

Comment: @Rup As advised, I revised the pom.xml file to include the ipojo eventadminhandler dependency and maven-ipojo-plugin....it generates the bundle, but still gives errors. I'll edit the post to show you the current picture of affairs (if you get time)

Comment: I removed the <goals> from the pom.xml file. It compiles now!

Comment: Great! You could consider posting an answer, particularly if you understand why that fixed the problem and can explain what was wrong.

Comment: It compiled. But didn't show any output.

Comment: I've tried another example. It still doesn't work.

Comment: It's possible Felix won't let you `System.out.println`. You could try using [the logger](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html) instead?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm working on it. So far I've not succeeded...but I'm trying. It compiles fine but raises bundle exceptions during run-time...I'll get back to you once I'm successful.

Comment: You should use either the ipojo annotation process (version must be align to other ipojo dep so 1.12.1)  or the metada.xml to describe your ipojo component. Not the two methods at same time.